# vertically center text inside a <summary>

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a summary tag for a  but the text inside the summary is at the top. How can I center it vertically

HTML

```
<details class="FAQ"><summary class="FAQ">Where can I find the most detailed information?</summary></details>
```

CSS

```
details.FAQ{
    padding:7px 7px 7px 29px;
    }

summary.FAQ{
    height: 29px; 
    background-color: #8CA6D2; 
    color: #231F20; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 1.3;
    }

summary.FAQ:hover{
    border:1px solid black; 
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a single line of the text in the `summary` then, giving a `line-height` equal to the `height`, will make the text aligned *vertically* at the center. So as per your css, the following will do it:

```
summary.FAQ {
  line-height: 29px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: wc, it would be great to both of us if you can accept the answer.

Comment: This only works for single line summaries, if the line is linewrapped a bunch of extra/unwanted vertical space is inserted.

Comment: @zrajm I have mentioned in the answer, that it will only work for text with a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if the same style you want then

```
summary.FAQ{
    height: 29px; 
    background-color: #8CA6D2; 
    color: #231F20; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
     line-height: 1.7;
     text-align:center
    }
```

Line height will work for you: line-height: 1.7; text-align:center; 
Here is you [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/varvind/8ZEbt/)

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to have anything to do with `<details>` or `<summary>` (in fact none of those tags are in the demo).